# CSS background url from base64 img on mobile

Tags: css, background, base64

I'm using to set background gradient via base64 img as shown:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2Y5ZmNmNyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlNmU2ZTYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
```

if you run it in your browse tab it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <linearGradient id="grad-ucgg-generated" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f9fcf7" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e6e6e6" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#grad-ucgg-generated)" />
</svg>
```

i would like to know why does on mobile it doesn't works?

As i  can see it works on pc for every browser, what about mobile so?

I'm on Android Galaxy

Comment: Hmmm you are saying à base64-encoded svg is throwing back a svg-image? what happens if you get rid of the XML-declaration and then try enoding it again? What mobile by the Way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you will need the XML declaration.  Try adding the DOCTYPE as well and then encode the entire SVG XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <linearGradient id="grad-ucgg-generated" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f9fcf7" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e6e6e6" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#grad-ucgg-generated)" />
</svg>
```